# I need the request in my decorator but I can't figure out how to get it in there

Tags: python, django

my deorator function...

```
def validate_captcha(view):
    '''Decorator to validate a captcha based on settings'''

    def failure():
        return HttpResponse('You need to complete the captcha, please refresh and try again')

    if request.method == 'POST':

        url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"
        values = {
            'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
            'response': request.POST.get(u'g-recaptcha-response', None),
            'remoteip': request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR", None),
        }

        data = urllib.urlencode(values)
        req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        result = json.loads(response.read())

        # result["success"] will be True on a success
        if result["success"]:
            return view
        else:
            return fail
    return fail
```

and then my view...

```
@validate_captcha
def sendemail(request):
    ...
```

I could put the request in the decorator args, but then it is undefined when i put it in the view args. I tried calling it a few others ways without success, how would you put it in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a *wrapper function*:

```
def validate_captcha(view):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':

            url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"
            values = {
                'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
                'response': request.POST.get(u'g-recaptcha-response', None),
                'remoteip': request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR", None),
            }

            data = urllib.urlencode(values)
            req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            result = json.loads(response.read())

            # result["success"] will be True on a success
            if result["success"]:
                return view
            else:
                return fail
        return fail
    return wrap
```

Make sure study this awesome and quite detailed overview on decorators in Python (I personally think, it is one of the best SO answers ever):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/771848

Comment: Thanks for this. I got all up in my head about "Oh I don't know Django" so I couldn't think in Python anymore! :)

Comment: @AdamSmith exactly, Python comes built into Django :)

Comment: @alecxe your suggestion worked, thanks, but I am getting another error now that is confusing me...haha...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077276/attribute-error-when-writing-a-captcha-decorator

Comment: @alecxe that's actually a really useful feature of Django :)