# Attribute Error when writing a captcha decorator

Tags: python, django

I wrote a captcha decorator...

```
def validate_captcha(view):
    '''Decorator to validate a captcha based on settings'''

    def failure():
        return HttpResponse('There was an error, please refresh and try again')

    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':

            url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"
            values = {
                'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
                'response': request.POST.get(u'g-recaptcha-response', None),
                'remoteip': request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR", None),
            }

            data = urllib.urlencode(values)
            req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            result = json.loads(response.read())

            # result["success"] will be True on a success
            if result["success"]:
                return view
            else:
                return failure
        return failure
    return wrap
```

and then used it on a view...

```
@validate_captcha
def sendemail(request):
    ...
```

but then I get an attribute error...

```
Traceback:
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  223.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_response
  138.         if response.status_code == 404 and not settings.DEBUG:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /ko/contact/sendemail
Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

I THINK...this is happening because it returned a function, but I cannot figure out why django is treating this as a response, because the response was already handled in my decorator and I verified that it made it through to the return point 'result["success"]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should call the `failure()` function so that you actually have an `HttpResponse` returned from the wrapping decorator. Replace:

```
return failure
```

with:

```
return failure()
```

And, the same goes for the `view`, call it:

```
return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: that worked, I could have sworn that I tried that in my first attempts and had it fail, but thanks :)